# How to retrieve a list of indexes of white pixels whose neighbor are black using Python PIL and Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've been looking for hours to find a question similar, but nothing has satisfied me.
My problem is: I've a PIL image (representing a canal) already converted into a Numpy array (using the "L" mode of PIL), and I'd like to retrieve the white pixels whose neighbor are black (their indexes in fact), without using **for loops** (the image is really huge).
I thought of *np.where* but I don't know how I should use it to solve my problem, and I also don't know if it would be faster than using **for loops** (because my aim would be reaching this goal with the fastest solution).

I hope I'm clear enough, and I thank you in advance for your response!

EDIT: for example, with this image ([a simple canal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZieB.jpg), it is already a black and white image, so the *image.convert('L')* isn't really useful here, but the code should be generic if possible), I'd do something like that:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(canal)
image = image.convert("L")
array = np.asarray(image)
l = []
for i in range(1, len(array) - 1):
    for j in range(1, len(array[0]) - 1):
        if array[i][j] == 255 and (array[i+1][j] == 0 or array[i-1][j] == 0 or array[i][j+1] == 0 or array[i][j-1] == 0):
             l.append((i, j))
```

and I'd hope to obtain *l* as fast as possible :)
I've colored the pixels I need in red in the next image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrFpN.png).

EDIT2: thank you all for the help, it worked!

Comment: For loops are slow because of the interpreter. What about something like `np.where(np.all(image == 0, axis=2))`?

Comment: @BrainFlooder I've written the kind of code I first think to use, but since my real map is 6600x30800 pixels, for loops are clearly not the best option I think :(

Comment: @JérômeRichard I didn't think of `np.all`, it may be useful if I could check if my white pixels are indeed "border pixels", but how can I modify your code line to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can use views: `np.where(np.all(image[1:-1, 1:-1] == 0, axis=2))`

Comment: I'll try it, thank you already for your help :D

Comment: I'd also look at `np.diff`.  Changes of +255 are black to white, -255 white to black. Run it once for each axis.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `numba` just-in-time compiler to speed up your loop.

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def find_highlow_pixels(img):
    pixels = []
    for j in range(1, img.shape[0]-1):
        for i in range(1, img.shape[1]-1):
            if (
                img[j, i] == 255 and (
                    img[j-1, i]==0 or img[j+1,i]==0 or 
                    img[j, i-1]==0 or img[j, i+1]==0
                )
            ):
                pixels.append((j, i))
    return pixels
```

Comment: Numba may be a bit overkill here and may not be more efficient than Numpy (at least the next release that will strongly improve the speed of np.where and a bit methods like np.all). That being said, there are few things that can be applied to improve the code. One is the use of the eager compilation so not to pay the compilation cost at runtime. This can be done by adding a *signature*. Another thing is to use contiguous array in the signature to enable SIMD vectorization. And finally using Numpy array is generally much faster than lists (although lists are easier to use).

Comment: Hi @JérômeRichard, I would not say that using arrays is always faster than using a list. To me they correspond to different use cases. While an array is useful if the size is known in advance, the list has the advantage to serve as a stack.  As said in the question: *the image is really huge*, so allocating memory for the diffs may become expensive as well. If the amount of relevant pixels is small compared to the total amount of pixels (which I expect), using the list can become the preferable solution.

Comment: Looking at the example image (500x500) I agree with @JérômeRichard that a custom function could be overkill if all you want is edge detection. There is a bunch of literature about it. Maybe start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection. There are libraries which provide the tools you need, see for example https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.canny or https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html which may help you to cover more general cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that came to my mind would be using the minimum filter. However, I would expect it to be slower than the first proposed solution, but could be useful to build more on top of it.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import minimum_filter

# create a footprint that only takes the neighbours into account
neighbours = (np.arange(9) % 2 == 1).reshape(3,3)

# create a mask of relevant pixels, img should be your image as array
mask = np.logical_and(
    img == 255,
    minimum_filter(img, footprint=neighbours) == 0
)

# get indexes
indexes = np.where(mask)

# as list
list(zip(*indexes))
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory space is not considered, I prefer manipulation of masks like the following.

```py
# Step 1: Generate two masks of white and black.
mask_white = img == 255
mask_black = img == 0

# Step 2: Apply 8-neighborhood dilation on black mask
# if you want to use numpy only, you need to implement dilation by yourself.
# define function of 8-neighborhood dilation
def dilate_8nb(m):
    index_row, index_col = np.where(m)
    ext_index_row = np.repeat(index_row,9)
    ext_index_col = np.repeat(index_col,9)
    ext_index_row.reshape(-1,9)[:, :3]  += 1
    ext_index_row.reshape(-1,9)[:, -3:]  -= 1
    ext_index_col.reshape(-1,9)[:, ::3]  += 1
    ext_index_col.reshape(-1,9)[:, 2::3]  -= 1
    ext_index_row = np.clip(ext_index_row, 0, m.shape[0]-1)
    ext_index_col = np.clip(ext_index_col, 0, m.shape[1]-1)
    ret = m.copy()
    ret[ext_index_row, ext_index_col] = True
    return ret

ext_mask_black = dilate_8nb(mask_black)
# or just using dilation in scipy
# from scipy import ndimage
# ext_mask_black = ndimage.binary_dilation(mask_black, structure=ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 2))

# Step 3: take the intersection of mask_white and ext_mask_black
mask_target = mask_white & ext_mask_black

# Step 4: take the index using np.where
l = np.where(mask_target)

# modify this type to make it consistency with your result
l = list(zip(*l))
```